# displays high contrast shade in tooltip

Tags: c#

iam trying to achieve tooltip in disabled checkbox which is inside the group box, after googling i came to know that hovering will not work out , so i tried mousemove method , it displays tooltip , before loading the tooltip it displays shade (a kind of black border) and then displays the content. can anyone help me to resolve this ?
please view the screenshots [toolbox loads with black shade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d75YU.png),then [displays the content in tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ36a.png)

```
private void UserInterface_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //creating object reference for tooltip
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

    CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[] { checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5};

    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!(boxes[i].Checked))
        {
            if (e.X >= boxes[i].Location.X && e.X <= boxes[i].Location.X + boxes[i].Width && e.Y >= boxes[i].Location.Y && e.Y <= boxes[i].Location.Y + boxes[i].Height)
            {
                toolTip.Show("checkbox tooltip" + boxes[i].Text, boxes[i], boxes[i].Width / 2, boxes[i].Height / 2, 150);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the Tool-tip in disabled group-box. Don't waste your time with this event.

Comment: hi vijay , i'm getting tooltip, but it is displaying some black border and then loads the contents in the tooltip .

Comment: could you share the screen shot ?

Comment: ya i have posted above .